# Why is my field not displayed?

Tags: views, theming, entities

I got a template for drupal 8 and modifying a content type, when editing a new field, it does not show up.

I'm attaching the images of the structure (fields, form display, display), creation of content and impression.

[image: 1 FLIDS]
[image: 2 FORM DISPLAY]
[image: 3 DISPLAY]
[image: CREATE CONTENT]
[image: IMPRESSION, FINAL VISUALIZATION]
For more that adds any field I do not manage to make it visualize at the end, in web portal

AND, As in the last page of print (celestial circles) I can not edit that, for more that I have edited in: filds, form display and display. Please where else is it that you can edit these texts in drupal 8?

Can someone help me please

regards

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a drupal-commerce question. Please update the tags.

Comment: In the screenshot, you haven't selected any value in the widget. But that's probably just the screenshot. Please show your template code and any preprocess function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template most likely does not print content directly only specific fields, you need to add {{ content.field_name }} to the template, where you want to have it displayed.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do that? Or some example link to help me. thank you very much for your help. regards

Comment: I don't really know what else to tell you, you should find enough generic tutorials on how to work with templates in Drupal 8, start with enabling twig debug mode (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates), which tells you which template file is used. Open that and start changing it by adding your field as shown by example in my answer. See also http://www.md-systems.ch/blog/techblog/2017/02/20/twig-and-entity-field-api-or-how-to-take-control-of-nodehtmltwig